# Python Reading Commands from File

Tags: python, file, input, line

I am new to python and am trying to open a file, look at its contents, and do something based on those contents.

For example, if a file contains:

```
Buy 100 20.00
Buy 400 10.00
Sell 200 28.00
```

How would i read the file one line at a time, assign each item to a variable, and do things based on those variables?

For example, I read the first line, and

```
 command = Buy
 quantity = 100
 price = 20.00
```

I do something with that, then read the next line

```
command = Buy
quantity = 400
price = 10.00
```

Hope this is clear, thank you

Comment: What's wrong with splitting each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for a_line in f:
        command, quantity, price = a_line.split()
        print(command, quantity, price)
        # do what you want with these values here
        # please note that quantity and price are strings. need to 
        # change them to float if you want to do some calculations.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def buy(num, value):
    # a sample Buy function
    print("Buy {} at {}".format(num, value))

def sell(num, value):
    # a sample Sell function
    print("Sell {} at {}".format(num, value))

# command dispatch table - get function based on string
command = {"Buy": buy, "Sell": sell}

def main():
    with open("file.txt") as inf:
        for line in inf:
            cmd, num, val = line.split()
            command[cmd](int(num), float(val))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```